# Shorten split() code or write in elegant way of python

Tags: python, split

Is there any other way for me to shorten this code or write the code in more elegant way that could get into same result?

```
email= "info@helena.com"
name=email.split("@")[1]
name=name.split(".")[0]
print(name)
```

Comment: Only the domain name or all parts of user, domain and TLD?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean? But the result that I want is the user name which is "helena".

Comment: Well, then you already have two answer. But usually you name parts of an e-mail like this: `username@domain_name.tld`. Your example is the `info` user/account for the website/company/entity `helena.com`

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can write it in one line

```
email= "info@helena.com"
name=email.split("@")[1].split(".")[0]
print(name)
```

Is that more elegant is unsure

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for additional problems, there's always regex.

```
import re
email= "info@helena.com"
print(re.search(r"@(.*)\.", email).group(1))
```

Seems like an answer in search of a problem though.